# Push Notifications for different platforms and devices in China

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I read a lot of articles about how to implement Push Notifications with Cordova (and Ionic 2) and I'm not sure how to implement that in China when not using Google's push server.

I think using https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push is a good idea. But all the Howtos are focussing on creating an account in Google's FCM which is not really helpful in China. I doubt Chinese phones use Google to poll for notifications. Which leads to my next question.

**I was assuming that there exists only one central push service for all platforms** (Android, iOS and Windows) **and vendors** for the following reasons:

- One platform is only polling from one fixed push server to save battery life.
- If an app (server side) is sending a push notification, it does not know anything about the receiver's device, so it can only count on a centralized service delivering the message to the device regardless of platform or vendor.

But do Apple, Google and Microsoft all use the same push service? I doubt it, and that's what makes me confused. Also, if I'm in China, as Google's services are unstable here, the Android phones distributed in China are not using Google and even not install Google Play Store.

When I install a Chinese app (hosted in China) on a German phone (Android) I still get all notifications for that app even if I'm obviously polling from Google's push server. That means, the notification messages of the Chinese app is somehow delivered to Google.

**The only explanation for that is that the different push services are working together.** Is that the case? If so, than does it make a difference where I create an account (Google FCM: https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/gcm-setup-for-android-push-notifications-656cfdd8adbd#.rr2lfivfh), it is still usable on different push servers? Also, when I send a notification, could I use any server all over the world?

How can I find out which push server my phone is connected with (Android)?

A lot of confusing here, I really appreciate if someone could bring light to that topic :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason GCM / FCM does not work in China is simply because the Great Firewall of China blocks connectivity to all the various Google services, FCM included.

Also, most, if not all, China-sold phones do not come with Google Play Services, a requirement for FCM to work.

Even if you were to take a German phone, as you mentioned, into China, it would not receive notifications albeit having Google Play Services, due to the firewall.

But there are alternative push notification gateways you could use instead, which are far more reliable and do not depend on Google Play Services. One of those is Pushy.

Pushy (https://pushy.me/) offers a highly-reliable push notification gateway for Android apps that works independently from FCM, using its own background MQTT connection. It also offers iOS support so you can push all of your users via a single API for cross-platform support.

Full disclosure: I founded Pushy.

Comment: I already run my own push notification service in China. For Apple APNS, though we have no choice but to use api.push.apple.com using relayrides/pushy library, it works but often the service is very sluggish. Since our alerts are time sensitive, this creates problem. A curl timing test shows that hitting the end-point from US takes about 0.3 seconds whereas it would take anyway from 3-22 seconds and occasionally just blocked for long time. Will your APNS service circumvent this problem?

Comment: Do you mean that overseas it would take 3 - 22 seconds?

Comment: I have experienced the APNS client keep getting disconnected, then I test with 'time curl https://api.push.apple.com'. It would take anywhere from 3 seconds to over 1 minutes to complete, averaging about 20 seconds. The relayride/pushy client also experienced SSL handshake timeout error often. So I suspect the network is not reliable.

Comment: Not sure exactly what is causing your issue, but you could work around it by using Pushy, which exposes a HTTP REST API that lets you send push notifications to iOS devices, and we interface with APNs on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

With Cordova, you can use the plugin [cordova-plugin-xiaomi-push](https://github.com/waitaction/cordova-plugin-xiaomi-push) done with the Xiaomi Android SDK. I have tested and it works well with all the phones when the application is running. And even when the app is closed with Xiaomi phones :)

The advantage to use Xiaomi is that their [developer website](http://mipush.global.xiaomi.com/)  is in English and their server's APIs are simple.

There are also 2 plugins for [Huawei](https://github.com/waitaction/cordova-plugin-huawei-push) and [Oppo](https://github.com/waitaction/cordova-plugin-oppo-push), which work well with the respective brand phones, even if the app is closed. But the API side is more complicated than with Xiaomi. To cover all the supplier with notifications when app is closed, it seems necessary to build one version per manufacturer/stores which include the required plugin (That is possible using a bash script) + build a push server that would send the notification to the right provider.

Answer (score 0):

Google FCM notification not works in china country. You have to use some different push notification provider like Pushy.

[For China Country, I used pushy service. You can go through this link if you wanna interested to use pushy service. Please check this link.This will help you](https://pushy.me)